# Are $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ independent?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence

Let $Y = (Y_1,Y_2)$ be a random vector with denisty
$$f(y_1,y_2) = \frac{2}{\pi} e^{-\frac{y^2_1+y^2_2}{2}} I(y_1 >0,y_2>0)$$

Are $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ independent?

Two variables are independent if $f(x,y) = f(x)f(y)$

Then could I make the argument that they are independent since
$$f(y_1) = \frac{1}{\pi}e^{\frac{-Y^{2}_1}{2}}$$ and
$$f(y_2) = 2e^{\frac{-Y^{2}_2}{2}}$$

Comment: What about the indicator function? You are right so far, of course( Note that each of $f(y_1),f(y_2)$ needs to integrate to $1$, so the split of the constants is not correct, but that can be done anyway).

Comment: @астонвіллатересалисбон since they don't integrate to 1. Then they aren't independent right?

Comment: No no, it means that you got the constants wrong in the expressions for $f(y_1,f(y_2))$. The original $f(y_1,y_2)$ integrates to $1$, so a shuffle of the constants should work out : it is the variable part that should split nicely, and you have shown that, except for the indicator (you have not split $1_{y_1>0,y_2>0}$ as a product of some function of $y_1$ and some function of $y_2$. This is easily possible).

Comment: I think you have to manage the constants, because if integrate your $f(y_1)$ and $f(y_2)$ that does not  give 1

Comment: Yeah, i guess i cant not see it, my two constants are 2 and pi and either combination of those 2 integrates to 1. If my indicator is 1 for y>0 then the integration should be from 0 to infinity right?

Comment: Your marginals do not integrate to 1. The constants should be $\sqrt{2/\pi}$ in both cases and of course you have to include the indicator also.

Comment: You should anticipate that the two marginals p.d.f. have the same coefficients due to the apparent symmetry of the joint p.d.f..  And therefore, that constant would be $\surd(2/\pi)$, *if* the marginals are indeed for independent variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to verify that the join distribution can be factorized as follows

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\mathbb{1}_{(0;+\infty)}(x)\times\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}\mathbb{1}_{(0;+\infty)}(y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$$

Thus X,Y are independent, both disributed as a conditional Standard Gaussian (conditioned on $X>0$,$Y>0$)

You can get the same result integrating the opposite variable to find a marginal density